# Spring cannot find bean

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I do not know if it will be helpful but I need to tell you the full genesis of my problem - how it started.

Everything was correct until I started build the `security`.

The first problem I had was with my `SecretKey` `bean` from `@Configuration` `class` which `Spring` couldn't find. I solved this by creating `init` method with `@PostConstruct` annotation.

Then the second problem occured which I hadn't had before -

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

I solved this by adding `(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` to `@SpringBootApplication` annotation in my `main` `class`

And then the third and currently last problem occured which I also hadn't had before.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************    

Description:
    
    Parameter 0 of constructor in com.app.persistence.repository.PersonRepositoryImpl required a bean of type 'com.app.persistence.dao.PersonEntityDao' that could not be found.
    
    
    Action:
    
    Consider defining a bean of type 'com.app.persistence.dao.PersonEntityDao' in your configuration.
```

---

```
   public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
        Optional<Person> findByName(String name);
        Optional<Person> findByAddress(Address address);
    }
```

---

```
  public interface PersonEntityDao extends JpaRepository<PersonEntity, Long> {
        Optional<PersonEntity> findByName(String name);
    }
```

---

```
   @Repository
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class PersonRepositoryImpl implements Repository {
        private final PersonEntityDao personEntityDao;
        //methods overriden from Repository
    }
```

Paths are like that: `PersonRepository` is in `domain` `module` in package: `com.app.model.person.repository.PersonRepository`, then `PersonEntityDao` is in `web` `module` in package: `com.app.persistence.dao.PersonEntityDao` and `PersonRepositoryImpl` is also in `web` `module` in package: `com.app.persistence.repository.PersonRepositoryImpl`. The `main class` is in web module in package: `com.app.App`

I really do not know why there is the problem with this beans because I haven't changed anything in code, just added new directory `com.app.security` where I even do not use any of these `classes` above.

This project is `multi-module` project where `Repository` is in `domain` module, then `RepositoryImpl` and `EntityDao` are in `web` module (there is also my `main class`)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.app")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecretKey secretKey() {
        return Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.ES512);
    }
}
```

then I wanted to use this in my `TokensService` class like this:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TokensService {
    private final SecretKey secretKey;
    
    public TokensDto createTokens(Authentication authentication) {
        //here I used this secretKey in 
        //Jwts.builder().[...].signWith(secretKey).build();
    }
```

and this error occured: `Error creating bean with name 'secretKey'`

so I created `init` method like this:

```
 @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        var context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(AppConfig.class);
        context.refresh();
        secretKey = context.getBean("secretKey", SecretKey.class);
    }
```

and the bean error was solved, but error with `DataSource: 'url'` occured which I had not had before

Comment: Usually the error about "attribute is not specified" occurs when you forgot to define a profile, or when you run your Spring Boot application with the wrong profile, so that the property is not found in the `.properties` file.

Comment: Is the configuration file in the application project or is it part of a module? Are you '@Import'-ing the Configuration inside your application? Can you try to remove the '@ComponentScan' annotation, or change the scope of it such that it does not include the  repository folders? Please dont exclude the datasource auto configuration since it seems like it is used by the multimodule project

Comment: the configuration file is in `web` module where the `main` class is. If I delete `@ComponentScan` then I get  errors `Error creating bean with name '<beanName>'`

Comment: Error creating bean with name '<beanName>'. Does spring not tell you which bean it needs?

Comment: it tells, I just wrote <beanName> because there were 3 different beans with this error. I mean, I use my `secretKey` `bean` in `TokensService` class and I use methods from `TokensService` in other class and there were errors with those classes too

Comment: What happens when you now remove the '@PostConstruct'-Method (init)?

Comment: then I got three errors in this order: `Error creating bean with name 'webConfig'`,  `Error creating bean with name 'tokensService'`, `Error creating bean with name 'secretKey'` where the `webConfig` and `tokensService` has `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException` and `secretKey` has `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this in PersonRepositoryImpl

```
private final PersonEntityDao personEntityDao;

@Autowire
public PersonRepositoryImpl(PersonEntityDao personEntityDao){
 this.personEntityDao = personEntityDao;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the entity is not initialize, i suspect that since you excluded the dbautoconfig :
(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})

Try correcting the url error that you were getting due to this.

Comment: the only way that helped me to solve this `url` problem was this `(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` added to `@SpringBootApplication`. I also tried adding the `driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` to my `application.yml` but the same problem occurs.

Comment: driverClassName is not a url, a url is where your db is hosted ,see below required properties:

spring.datasource.url = http://localhost:3306/testdb
spring.datasource.username = [username]
spring.datasource.password = [password]
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver